# jupyter qtconsole does not connect to existing kernel

Tags: jupyter, qtconsole

- %qtconsole
- jupyter qtconsole --existing
- jupyter qtconsole --existing path/kernel-7596.json

only opens a **empty/dead qtconsole** not connected to the kernel (under win32 and linux64)

however *jupyter console --existing* is connecting to the kernel.

Bug in qtconsole? Any help would be appreciated?

----------INFO----------

Jupyter QtConsole 4.2.1
Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (32-bit)| (default, Mar  4 2016, 15:28:01) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]

Comment: just hit return in the empty qtconsole and it will come to live !!

Comment: I second the above.  Try hitting "return" in the console.  I spent 40 minutes trying to debug this...

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, and elsewhere around the web:

Try hitting "return" in your blank console.